# MYSQL query and inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I am trying to figure out how to get all the messages for both my `user_id` and my friends `user_id`

My database layout is

```
messages - user_id, message 
friends - user_id_1, user_id_2
```

My `user_id` could be 1 or 2 as well as my friends could be either 1 or 2, just depends on whom send the friend request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My basic query is below.

```
select * from messages WHERE user_id = $user_id
```

Comment: Simple way to do this is to run a separate query beforehand **just** getting the user IDs of your friends, then `implode(', ', $friend_id_array)`, and `select ... where user_id in('" . $imploded_user_ids . ', ' . $your_user_id . "')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from messages 
where user_id = $user_id
or user_id in (select user_id_1 from friends where user_id_2 = $user_id) 
or user_id in (select user_id_2 from friends where user_id_1 = $user_id)
```